# .on not working with 1.9.1 jquery version

Tags: jquery, event-delegation

I want to hide appended div from body. I am using `.on` with jQuery 1.9.1, but it is not working.

```
<head>
    <style>
        .brd { border:solid 1px #FF0000; background:#CCCCCC}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function appendHtml (msg) {
            var htm= '<div class="brd">"' + msg + '"  <a href="javascript:void(0)">close</a></div>';
            $('body').append(htm);
        };
        $(function () {
            $('a').on('click', function () {
                $('.brd').remove();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span onmouseover="appendHtml('hiii there')">append html</span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `on` on elements already present in `document`. In your case, `a` was created dynamically. So, `on` is not working.

Choose nearest parent of the element, on which you want an event to be triggered.

In your case `body` or `document`

```
$(document).on('click','a',function(){
  $('.brd').remove();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use delegation for dynamic elements:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click','a',function(){
       $('.brd').remove();
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this syntax

```
 $(document).on('click','a',function(){
       $('.brd').remove();
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation on a ascendant DOM element of `div.brd a`:

```
$('body').on('click','div.brd a',function(){
     $(this).parent().remove();
})
```

And because the close button is a `div.brd` child you can use `$(this).parent().remove()` instead to a faster perfomance